# take picture just in Android 12 the result code is zero

Tags: android, camera, android-fileprovider, android-12, startactivityforresult

I try to take the picture Uri in the onActivityResult() and i'm get resultCode == 0 only on Android 12.
on all the other devices I tested it works fine.

this is the code to start gallery and camera

```
    final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
    File.separator + "HofitApp" + File.separator);
    root.mkdirs();
    final String fname = "AddProductImage.jpg";
    final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);

    //      mProductImageUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
    mProductImageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", sdImageMainDirectory);

    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mProductImageUri);
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // Filesystem.
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    // Chooser of filesystem options.
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");

    // Add the camera options.
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));

    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, EXT_PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Has anyone have this problem and know how to fix it?

I have tried all kind of ways, i try to change from `Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory)`
to FileProvider and still not working properly, result code is zero after taking a picture.

thanks

Comment: `root.mkdirs();` Replace by: `if (!root.exists()) if (!root.mkdirs()) return;`. Try again then tell us.

Comment: `chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));`That does not make sense. Not for ACTION_GET_CONTENT. What did you have in mind?
`

Comment: i would suggest Better fire separate Intents for camera and gallery with an `AlertDialog`  also pass and `EXTRA_OUTPUT` Uri for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` . make sure ur create file is exposed with FileProvider so that it can be written by camera Apps . I haven work on this from a long time there has been some major changes in storage parts in recent years So i suggest follow some tutorial . its pretty basic stuff and should work just fine ..

Answer (score 0):

Replace your Temp Image Location -

```
 final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
 File.separator + "HofitApp" + File.separator);
```

to

```
final File root =  context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)?.path+File.separator+"HofitApp"+File.separator;
```

and camera capture intent go like that -

```
val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri)

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    cameraIntent.clipData = ClipData.newRawUri("", uri)
    cameraIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
}

startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_CAPTURE_REQUEST)
```